# OpenLayer 3 - GeoJSON - feature is null

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-3

I'm trying to get country string by coordinates, but feature is null.

Why feature is null? how could I fix it?

I tested with onclick **event.pixel** and it does returns feature but then I use **map.getPixelFromCoordinate** to get **pixel** feature becomes null

```
var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        url: 'https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/examples/data/geojson/countries.geojson',
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
    })
});

var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [ vectorLayer],
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
        center: [0, 0],
        zoom: 1
    }),
    logo:false
  });
```

this does not work

```
map.once('postrender', function() {
    var pixel = map.getPixelFromCoordinate([-0.0508, 51.5160]);

    var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function(feature) { 
        return feature;
    });

    console.log("Country:"+feature.get("name"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because by the time `postrender` event is called, loading of features is not complete. You can use [`postcompose`](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.render.Event.html#event:postcompose) event on `vectorLayer` instead. If the function is going to be more complex I would recommend using `ol.source.Vector`'s [loader](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.source.Vector.html) function.

```
vectorLayer.on('postcompose', function () {
    var pixel = map.getPixelFromCoordinate(ol.proj.fromLonLat([-0.0508, 51.5160]));
    var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function (feature) {
        return feature;
    });
    console.log("Country:"+feature.get("name"));
});
```

Also you seem to be passing `EPSG:4326` coordinates which needs transformation to `EPSG:3857` (which is used by OpenLayers by default).